# How can I create a dropdown list in Wicket?

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, wicket

I'm trying to populate items in a dropdown list.

I've achieved getting values from my database, but I can't add them in a dropdown list.

```
public List<String> getNames(){
        List<String> polNames = new LinkedList<String>();
                try {
            String query ="SELECT names FROM clinics";
            Statement statement = this.connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);
            while(result.next()){
                polNames.add(result.getString("name"));
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException ex){
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return polNames;
    }
```

Above, I assigned the values to `polNames`. I want `polNames` to be added to the dropdown list.

Also, when clicking a value from list, I want to do a new query. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the list, you can use [the `DropDownChoice` class](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/DropDownChoice.html). Here's a sample of what it might look like:

```
DropDownChoice<String> clinicNames =
    new DropDownChoice<String>("clinicNames",
                               new PropertyModel<String>(this, "selectedName"),
                               polNames) {
        // @Override
        // public void onSelectionChanged() {
        //     // Generate and submit your query here
        // }
    };

// EDIT: onSelectionChanged() is a final method; use this instead
OnChangeAjaxBehavior clinicNamesListener = new OnChangeAjaxBehavior() {
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        // Generate and submit your query here
    }
};
clinicNames.add(clinicNamesListener);
```

This would make a new dropdown list with Wicket ID of "clinicNames," populated with the values in `polNames`, that updates the `selectedName` value in your code.

Comment: onSelectionChanged() cannot implement onSelectionChanged() in org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IOnChanegeListener attempting to assign weaker access privileges, was public.

Comment: <form wicket:id="form">
       <select name="clinics" wicket:id="clinicNames"></select>
   </form>

Comment: This means that you declared wicket:id=form in your markup, but that you either did not add the component to your page at all, or that the hierarchy does not match

Comment: where can i add the form tag?

Comment: @jacop, sorry, `onSelectionChanged` should have been public, I just forgot to type that in earlier. Added now. You can add the form in your code pretty much anywhere, except that it obviously has to be ready before you call `form.add(clinicNames)`.

Comment: @jacop, you're right, that was a final method. I have updated again. There's no need to subclass `DropDownChoice` at all; I left the old code there as a comment in an attempt to be more clear.

Comment: You should also consider putting the logic from getNames() into the load()-method of a LoadableDetachableModel to avoid excessive database traffic. A LoadableDetachableModel only calls load() once per request cycle. Insert a log statement or a breakpoint in getNames() to see how many queries you can save. :)

Comment: @DaG, good point! I was trying to keep my answer somewhat easy to understand, and didn't think about what my comment would be replaced with. (I rarely deal with databases though, so I might have missed it even if I had thought about it.)